# I need to find the Daily Max value for the previous 30 days

Tags: sql-server-2008, max

I am using Microsft SQL 2008.
I need to find the individual Daily Max value for the running previous 30 days.  Here is the Query which I am currently using and a sample result that I am currently getting.  Being that the data only increments as the day goes along I really only need the final entry of the day.  I know there are different ways to get what I am looking for I just need some assistance to get pointed in the right direction.

```
SELECT HISTORY.STATION, HISTORY.NAME, HISTORY.VALUE, HISTORY.TIME
FROM DATA.dbo.HISTORY HISTORY
WHERE (HISTORY.NAME='KWMAXD') AND (HISTORY.TIME>= dateadd("Day",-30,getdate()))
ORDER BY HISTORY.TIME, HISTORY.NAME DESC



SYST    KWMAXD  49040   2013-02-24 12:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49040   2013-02-24 13:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49040   2013-02-24 14:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49040   2013-02-24 15:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49040   2013-02-24 16:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49040   2013-02-24 17:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49040   2013-02-24 18:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49040   2013-02-24 19:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49040   2013-02-24 20:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49040   2013-02-24 21:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49040   2013-02-24 22:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49040   2013-02-24 23:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  28160   2013-02-25 00:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  28160   2013-02-25 01:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  28160   2013-02-25 02:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  28160   2013-02-25 03:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  28160   2013-02-25 04:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  30110   2013-02-25 05:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  33390   2013-02-25 06:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  33390   2013-02-25 07:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  33390   2013-02-25 08:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  33390   2013-02-25 09:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  33390   2013-02-25 10:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  33390   2013-02-25 11:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  33390   2013-02-25 12:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  33390   2013-02-25 13:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  33390   2013-02-25 14:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  33390   2013-02-25 15:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  36100   2013-02-25 16:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  40650   2013-02-25 17:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  47040   2013-02-25 18:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49650   2013-02-25 19:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49650   2013-02-25 20:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49650   2013-02-25 21:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49650   2013-02-25 22:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  49650   2013-02-25 23:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  43090   2013-02-26 00:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  43090   2013-02-26 01:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  43090   2013-02-26 02:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  43600   2013-02-26 03:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  45900   2013-02-26 04:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  50900   2013-02-26 05:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  55290   2013-02-26 06:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  55290   2013-02-26 07:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  55290   2013-02-26 08:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  55290   2013-02-26 09:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  55290   2013-02-26 10:59:00.000
SYST    KWMAXD  55290   2013-02-26 11:59:00.000
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the SQL Server [ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) for example `row_number()`:

```
select station,
  name,
  value,
  time
from
(
  SELECT h.STATION, h.NAME, h.VALUE, h.TIME,
    row_number() over(partition by cast(h.time as date) order by h.time desc) rn
  FROM HISTORY h
  WHERE (h.NAME='KWMAXD') 
    AND (h.TIME>= dateadd(DAY,-30,cast(getdate() as date)))
) src
where rn = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8ba5/4)

This could be expanded to `partition` the data by the `name` and `date` if you want to return more than one `name` at a time, so the query would be:

```
select station,
  name,
  value,
  time
from
(
  SELECT h.STATION, h.NAME, h.VALUE, h.TIME,
    row_number() over(partition by h.name, cast(h.time as date) order by h.time desc) rn
  FROM HISTORY h
  WHERE (h.TIME>= dateadd(DAY,-30,cast(getdate() as date)))
) src
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: +1 but should 30 days be keyed off of the time right now (meaning the answer could change every 5 minutes), or off of midnight this morning or midnight tonight? I'd consider casting `GETDATE()` to `DATE` as well, then adjusting the -30 is just +1 or -1.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are right, I altered it in my answer. Thanks as always! :)

Comment: Thank you both very much.  That is what I am needing.  I see where I need to cut it back to midnight.  I am just not following where exactly I need to the "GETDATE() to DATE then adjusting the -30 is just +1 or -1".